# jquery accordion jump and open to a specific section

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, modx

i use jquery + jquerui in modx and the accordion. I wan't to have a horizontal menu on the top where I can jump (scroll) to the section (which opens). How would I achieve this.
Right now my js looks like this:

```
/ Accordion
        $("#accordion").children("div").each( function() {
                var a = $(this).find("a");
                var ref = $(a).attr("href");
                $(a).attr("href", "#");
            $(this).find("div").load(ref);
        });

        $("#accordion").ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).accordion({
                header: "h2",
                active: true,
                collapsible: true,
                clearStyle: true,
                navigation: true
            });
        });
```

EDIT: my accordion gets build with wayfinder:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`6` &outerTpl=`outerTpl` &rowTpl=`rowTpl`]]
```

rowTpl:

```
<div>
        <h2><a href="[[+wf.link]]">[[+wf.title]]</a></h2>
        <div>
           <!-- placeholder for content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

outerTpl:

```
<div id="accordion">[[+wf.wrapper]]</div>
```

The topmenu (horizontal) gets called like this:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`6` &outerTpl=`QouterTpl` &rowTpl=`QrowTpl`]]
```

QrowTpl:

```
<li[[+wf.id]][[+wf.classes]]><a href="[[+wf.link]]" title="[[+wf.title]]" [[+wf.attributes]]>[[+wf.linktext]]</a>[[+wf.wrapper]]</li>
```

QouterTpl

```
<ul class="arrowunderline">[[+wf.wrapper]]</ul>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [activate method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) to programmatically open an accordion panel.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tuando/CA8KV/1/) fiddle for an example.

Comment: thanks this works! For reference: QrowTpl looks like this: <li><a href="#" class="section-link">[[+wf.linktext]]</a></li>

Answer (score 2):

NB. **activate** method is deprecated since jquery ui 1.9 and removed since 1.10. More info and alternative can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-activate-method).

Answer (score 1):

use this on `.ready` function

```
$("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active' , 3);
```

3 = the number of specific section in menu you want it active